# Ambiguous Call In Linq-To-Sql Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm still a little new to Linq-To-SQL and I'm having a problem when I try to use the join operator (doing the equivalent of an SQL inner join).

Get all the preferences for a user:

```
return (from u in DataContext.UserPreference
join p in DataContext.Preference on p.Id equals u.PreferenceId
where u.UserId = userId
select p).ToList();
```

Visual Studio tells me that the "join" operator in the query is an "ambiguous call" between the Enumerable class and the Queryable class.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: What are the full types of the two members (Preferece and UserPreference)?

Comment: My own types. They don't inherit anything besides dedicated interfaces.

MyApp.Entity.UserPreference : MyApp.Entity.IUserPreference
MyApp.Entity.Preference : MyApp.Entity.IPreference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your join is expressed the wrong way round - you should be using `u` first, then `p`:

```
return (from u in DataContext.UserPreference
        join p in DataContext.Preference on u.PreferenceId equals p.Id
        where u.UserId == userId
        select p).ToList();
```

Basically you use the first range variable on the left side of the join, and the second variable on the right side.

Usually this sort of error is spotted by the compiler which suggests exactly what's wrong. I don't know why it didn't in this case, but either way the above should be the fix.

Comment: That's very strange; why does the order matter?

Comment: here u.UserId == userId surely? An assignment inside a linq statement is usually pretty weird, and generates that error too.

Comment: @Jacob: Because of the way that query syntax is translated. It's a mostly mechanical translation which turns each part of a query expression into lambda expressions. You ended up with two lambda expressions of `p => u.PreferenceId` and `u => p.Id`.

Comment: @blowdart: Unless `UserId` is of type `bool` :) Fixed - I was just concentrating on the join, but it's a good point.

Comment: Which may in fact point to the original problem anyway, it's not order, it's the assignment operator in the query.

Comment: @blowdart: I'm not sure why the problem in the where clause would lead to an error pointing to the *join* clause being invalid. Both are problems, I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to disagree with Jon. You have an assignment operator in the 3rd line your query, and not the equality operator, so instead

```
return (from u in DataContext.UserPreference
        join p in DataContext.Preference on p.Id equals u.PreferenceId
        where u.UserId == userId
        select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Good spot, but it shouldn't cause an error re the join. Valid point, though

Comment: Ah but it does, every time I get that darned message it's always because I messed up == :)

Comment: then get over to Mads and Eric, and moan at them about compiler messages :) interesting

Comment: *grin* I should do, but they scare me :)